# Backbone collection and Backbone model events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have two views listening to separate events in my collection.

```
this.cartCollection.on('quantityAdded', this.QuantityAdded, this);          
this.cartCollection.on('quantitySubtracted', this.QuantitySubtracted, this);
this.cartCollection.on('salesPriceRateUpdated', this.UpdateCartItemPrice, this);
this.cartCollection.on('unitMeasureUpdated', this.ChangeItemPriceOnUnitMeasure, this);
this.cartCollection.on('warehouseCodeUpdated',this.ChangeItemPriceOnWarehouseCode,this)
this.cartCollection.on('quantityOrderedUpdated', this.UpdateCartItem, this);
this.cartCollection.on('quantityDefectiveUpdated', this.UpdateCartItem, this);
this.cartCollection.on('discountUpdated', this.UpdateCartItem, this);       
this.cartCollection.on('discountAppliedToAll', this.ApplyDiscountToAll, this);

this.cartCollection.on('clearedTransaction', this.VoidTransactionWithValidation, this)
```

on maintemplate.js i have this

```
this.collection.bind("add", this.ModelAdded, this);         
this.collection.bind("change", this.ModelChanged, this);
this.collection.bind("viewDetails", this.ShowItemDetails, this);
this.collection.bind("viewFreeStock", this.ShowFreeStock, this);
this.collection.bind("viewAccessory", this.ShowAccessory, this);
this.collection.bind("viewSubstitute", this.ShowSubstitute, this);
this.collection.bind("itemRemoved", this.RemoveItem, this);
this.collection.bind("reset", this.ReinitializeCart, this);
```

But on my template those events are from my model which is linked to my collection. After triggering `this.cartCollection.on('salesPriceRateUpdated', this.UpdateCartItemPrice, this);`

I'm updating the collection by `this.cartCollection.reset` then pass updated models `this.cartCollection.add(data)` after this when I trigger `salesPriceRateUpdated maintemplate`this.UpdateCartItemPrice' no longer catches any event. I even tried adding `{merge:true}` yet same results.

Any Ideas on how to properly preserve the event bindings? Thanks

Comment: can I see an example / jfiddle

Comment: sorry. It's quite big and intricate so I can't have an fiddle example right away. I'll try to replicate the problem though

Comment: Here's a basic fiddle that (I think) does what you described: http://jsfiddle.net/rbkfL/. The issue is not reproduced, everything works as expected. Can you try to reproduce the issue there?